# Is there an option to take a string and use it to access the dataframe with the same name in python?

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I have a function that is based on the "code" needed to do the same thing to different dataframes. So now that function repeats itself just with the change of the dataframe's name.

```
def function(t, d, code):
    if code == "champion":
        temp = champion_league.loc[(champion_league['match_date'] == d) & 
                                    (champion_league['kot'] < t)]
        if temp.empty:
            return 0
        else:
            return 1

    elif code == "europe":
        temp = earopean_leagues.loc[(earopean_leagues['match_date'] == d) & 
                                    (earopean_leagues['kot'] < t)]
        if temp.empty:
            return 0
        else:
            return 1
```

I tried to change the df names into the given code (where the given code is the same name as one of the dataframes). But, I get an error that string doesn't have a 'loc' attribute.

```
def while_champion_european_leagues(t, d, code):
    temp = code.loc[(code['match_date'] == d) & (code['kot'] < t)]
    if temp.empty:
            return 0
        else:
            return 1
```

### **How can I change my function so that It won't repeat itself and will access the right df based on the given "code"?**

Comment: Store them in a dictionary. **Don't use eval**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a mapping dict:

```
codes = {
    'champion': champion_league,
    'europe': european_leagues
}

def function(t, d, code):
    df = codes.get(code)  # df is champion_league or european_leagues
    temp = df.loc[(df['match_date'] == d) & (df['kot'] < t)]
    if temp.empty:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1
```